# Is it possible to retrieve financial data (findat) through the workfront API?

Tags: php, workfront-api

I am using the Workfront API and I am trying to retrieve the financial data of a project. Is it possible to search / get financial data directly through the Workfront API? For instance I can use the following code to get a project:

```
$getProject = $client->get('project', $myProjectName);
```

Can I do something like

```
$finData = $client->get('FINDAT', array('ID' => $myProjectName), array('*'));
```

Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with the API implementation that you're using, but from a Workfront perspective the answer is yes. You can query the FINDAT object directly by searching on projectID=.